# Partitions of a simple function, doesn't make sense.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and let $A_i,B_j$ be in $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\Omega = \uplus_{i=1}^n A_i = \uplus_{j=1}^m B_j$, ie they're finite disjoint unions.  Let $s$ be a simple function and $s = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i 1_{A_i}$ and $s = \sum_{j=1}^m \beta_j 1_{B_j}$, be two partitions of $s$, where $1_A(x) = 1, x\in A; =0, x\notin A$.  Then s also has the partition $s = \sum_{i,j}^{n,m} \alpha_i 1_{A_i \cap B_j}$, and a similar one for the $\beta_j$.  But doesn't this mean $\alpha_i = \beta_j$ for all $i,j$ and so this simple function is not interesting?  To see this let $\omega \in A_i \cap B_j$, then $s(\omega) = \alpha_i 1_{A_i \cap B_j}(w) = \alpha_i = $ similar for $\beta_j$.  But I'm sure I got something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that $\alpha_i=\beta_j$ for all pairs $(i,j)$ *such that $A_i\cap B_j$ is non-empty*.

Comment: Thanks.  I got scared for a moment.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.